# How to send one property file and a value as parameters to an Ant script?

Tags: ant

Is it possible to send one property file and a separate value as two different parameters to an Ant script ?

E.g. *build.xml propertyfile=propfile -Dname1=value1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM ;-) means see Ant manual [running Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options), f.e.

```
ant -f whatever.xml -propertyfile=/var/usr/foobar.properties -Dfoo=bar
```

multiple -Dkey=value or -propertyfile=path/to/propertyfile are possible